# dotlock permissions problems with dovecot and OS X 10.10.3++

Tags: macos, permissions, pop3, dovecot, inbox

I have installed `dovecot` on `OS X Yosemite` via `Homebrew`. But for some reason I can't get it to fully work properly anymore starting with the `10.10.3` system update by Apple. There's some kind of unsolvable permission issue when it comes to create the dotlock files when dovecot wants to access the INBOXes. Interestingly postfix has no problems creating the dotlock files in the very same directory.

```
$ dovecot --version
2.2.18
```

The default path setup in OS X, also officially supported/ documented in the dovecot wiki. I would like to keep it as that, as system updates usually change permissions here back anyway:

```
$ ls -lae /var/
...
drwxrwxr-x    3 root       mail        102 Aug 14 18:52 mail
...

$ ls -lae /var/mail
...
-rw-------  1 haru mail  542 Aug 14 18:53 haru
...
```

This was my initial setup until `OS X 10.10.2`. I removed bunch of irrelevant options from the output:

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/dovecot/local.conf
protocols = pop3
listen = localhost
# Note: user _dovecot is member of the 'mail' group.
default_internal_user = _dovecot
default_login_user = _dovenull
mail_location = mbox:~/.mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
```

All was working fine until the `OS X 10.10.3` update came along and suddenly `dovecot[PID]: pop3(haru): Error: setegid(privileged) failed: Operation not permitted` errors were dumped when fetching mails. It still could fetch mails, but failed to delete them from the INBOX, so with every fetch the same mails came in again and again.

After lots of research and random tries I ended up adding `mail_access_groups = mail` to the dovecot config. I don't really understand what the option does exactly though.

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/dovecot/local.conf 
protocols = pop3
listen = localhost
# Note: user _dovecot is member of the 'mail' group.
default_internal_user = _dovecot
default_login_user = _dovenull
mail_location = mbox:~/.mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
mail_access_groups = mail
```

All was working fine again until the `OS X 10.10.5` update came along yesterday and suddenly all hell broke lose and it was failing completely with `dovecot[PID]: pop3(haru): Fatal: setgroups(mail,) failed: Too many extra groups`.  Removing `mail_access_groups = mail` fixed this error, but brought back the previously described misbehaviors that started with 10.10.3. In the end I had to disable dotfile locking by removing the default `dotlock`entry from the `mbox_write_locks`option:

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/dovecot/local.conf 
protocols = pop3
listen = localhost
# Note: user _dovecot is member of the 'mail' group.
default_internal_user = _dovecot
default_login_user = _dovenull
mail_location = mbox:~/.mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
mail_privileged_group = mail
mbox_read_locks = fcntl
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
```

Do I miss something here or fail to understand? Why is the default permission setup (as described in dovecot's documentation) not working? Perhaps it's even some kind of incompatibility starting to appear with OS X 10.10.3, or some bug in dovecot?

Answer (score 1):

The failure with `setgroups()` comes from the fact that the user on the machine, where Dovecot runs has more than 16 groups assigned to it.

Run `id -G <user>` or `id <user>` as root (or as that user) to see the number of groups.

Unfortunately is macOS assigning a ton of groups to users to run fine-grained access control for stuff like screen-sharing. Luckily Dovecot has an option to set ranges of 'valid' gids. So you can set

```
last_valid_gid = 100
```

The number may be different for you.

I just ran into this and wrote about it here: http://pilhuhn.blogspot.com/2018/10/solution-for-dovecot-and-setgroups.html